# Pyspark: Using dataframe in ml algorithms

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I understand that in order to use ml.clustering Kmeans algorithm (actually any ml algos?) with dataframe, I need to have my dataframe in a certain shape: (id, vector[]), or something like that. How to I apply the right transformation to convert a regular table (stored in df) to the desired structure?
This is my df:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext


conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()
#-----------------------------
#creating DF:
l = [('user1', 2,1,4),('user2',3,5,6)]
temp_df = spark.createDataFrame(l)
temp_df.show()

+-----+---+---+---+
|   _1| _2| _3| _4|
+-----+---+---+---+
|user1|  2|  1|  4|
|user2|  3|  5|  6|
+-----+---+---+---+
```

I want to use:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
kmean = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmean.fit(temp_df)
```

and I get: IllegalArgumentException: u'Field "features" does not exist.'

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

`KMeans` require an input column of `vector` type which should be, if not configured otherwise, named `features`. You should use `VectorAssembler` to combine the features.

Please consult:

- [KMeans docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans)
- [VectorAssembler docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler)